# Task<TResult>.Result vs await a task

Tags: c#, task

I writing a small example to get value `5` in method `TestMethod`, I have 2 ways to do that:

```
    static async Task<int> TestMethod()
    {
        await Task.Delay(0);
        return 5;
    }

    static async Task Caller()
    {
        Task<int> test = TestMethod();
        int i = await test;
        Console.WriteLine("i: " + i);

        int k = test.Result;
        Console.WriteLine("k: " + k);
    }
```

The output:

> i: 5
>
> k: 5

So, my questions are: what's the difference between `await test` and `test.Result`? And when to use `await test`/`test.Result`?

Comment: Does the compiler gives you warning on the line `int k = test.Result;`? What happen if you do `k` first before `i`?

Comment: @Hendry the compiler gave no warning, no error

Comment: `Task.Result` is blocking, `await` is not. But in this case it doesn't matter because the Task is already finished by the time you call Result.

Comment: maybe you can try to simulate the blocking by increasing the delay time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### First version

```
static void Caller()
{
    Task<int> test = TestMethod();
    int k = test.Result;
    Console.WriteLine("k: " + k);
}
```

In this version the `async` keyword would be obsolete. This is a *synchronous* method. The executing thread blocks at `test.Result` until the task has finished.

#### Second version

```
static async Task Caller()
{
    Task<int> test = TestMethod();
    int i = await test;
    Console.WriteLine("i: " + i);
}
```

This is a (kind of) *asynchronous* version (it's not *really* asynchron, it's just a synchronous method run on a different thread). The difference to the first version is that the compiler builds a state machine for this.
So the control flow of the executing thread is returned to the caller of this method when `await test` is reached.
When the task has finished, the execution of this method is resumed at `Console.WriteLine` (or more precisely at the assignment to `i`).

For more information about what the compiler does you can read for example [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/hh191443(v=vs.140)).

---

The second version is useful if you have a longer running task that you need to execute from an UI. Since the control is returned to the caller while awaiting the task, the UI thread is not blocked and your application stays responsive.

Answer (score 1):

`Task.Result` is equivalent to `Task.Wait` Method which blocks synchronously until the task is complete.

`await` on the other hand waits asynchronously till the task is completed.

If you can `await` is better.